# alexnet, dnn training issue. suggestion needed

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression

```
   inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Layer 1
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (11, 11), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu',
                kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01),
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lr),
                padding='same')(inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

# Layer 2
x = layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation='relu',
                kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01),
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lr), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

# Layer 3
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01),
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lr), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

# Layer 4
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01),
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lr), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

# Layer 5
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01),
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lr), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

# Layer 6
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Layer 7
x = layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Layer 8
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Layer 9
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Output layer
outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='linear')(x)

# Model instantiation
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

```
optimizer = optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
alex2.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mae',r_squared])

alex2_history = alex2.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=n_epochs, validation_data=(X_val,y_val),
                    batch_size=32)
```

this is my model that having image (single channel) as input and 14 continuous numbers.

following this the result from the training. (loss(MSE), MAE, r-squared)

[image]

there are many issues.

1. training does not seem to doing well.
2. maybe my model structure is wrong?

I tried to convert image as number and tried DNN, below is the result.(loss(MSE), MAE, r-squared)

[image]

I made the model complex to make it overfitted and seems to have good enough result.

which one should I use?

is there any better regressor structure ?